# Unable to start activity componentinfo (error en setContentView)

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

I know this is a highlight topic, but I can't find my mistake...

I have this in my `.MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

...

    public void abrirAppMovimiento(View view) {
        Intent mov = new Intent(this, Movimiento.class);
        startActivity(mov);
    }

...

}
```

This is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.emiliomorillanieto.practica3" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Movimiento"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And this is the class `.Movimiento`:

```
public class Movimiento extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_movimiento);
      }
 }
```

I have being debugging the app, and when the app enters to `.Movimiento`, `savedInstanceState` is `null`, but the error comes while trying to do "`setContentView`".

Why can it be possible, if I have my `activity_movimiento.xml` defined in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

My `activity_movimiento.xml` is a `RelativeLayout` with some buttons that play a sound when it's touched. Nothing special.

EDIT:
This is my `activity_movimiento.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gris_oscuro"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/volver"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="volverAtras"
        android:text="Volver" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_resultado"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:text="@string/resultado"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_chew"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="63dp"
        android:src="@raw/chew_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_laser"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@raw/laser_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_darth"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image_laser"
        android:src="@raw/darth_picture" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_luke"
        android:layout_width="150px"
        android:layout_height="150px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tv_resultado"

        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image_chew"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/image_chew"
        android:src="@raw/luke_picture" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the error:

```
02-08 11:12:29.126    9112-9112/com.example.emiliomorillanieto.practica3 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.emiliomorillanieto.practica3/com.example.emiliomorillanieto.practica3.Movimiento}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class <unknown>
 …
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 …
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 …
```

Comment: problem is inside your layout xml file

Comment: Please post your complete logcat error trace and layout `activity_movimiento` too.

Comment: It's done. I can't copy more error code without having problems. Let me know if it's enough for you. Otherwise, I'll try to copy the remaining error code!

Comment: @user3529582: As in Log :`Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` means one of ImageView src image size is very big

Comment: The biggest one is about 296kb. Is it too big for Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The inflate exception** is not a problem here , but here this comes from another issue in your layout that is *out of memory exception*.

A common issue is an **out of memory exception** when you are trying to inflate an imageview loading a drawable resource. If one of this resources has a high pixel resolution it would take a lot of memory causing then an inflate exception.

So do verify that the pixel resolution in your drawables images are minimum necessary for your layout.

Checkout [out of memory issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10127787/2826147) with good explaination.

Hope this helps.